# How can i use comm.Appdecoder in matlab written by some commands below?

Tags: matlab, decoder

When i run this simple coder and decoder written below, its result is wrong. I try various property of `comm.convolutional` and `comm.appdecoder` but when i calculate the error (`v`), it is not logical. I personally think that decoder has a problem with the number of input bits, but i dont know how to fix it. Is there anyone who do know it?

```
clc;    
clear all;    
Data1=randi([0 1],300,1);    
H=comm.ConvolutionalEncoder('TrellisStructure',poly2trellis(5,[23 35]),'TerminationMethod','Truncated');    
h=comm.APPDecoder('TrellisStructure',poly2trellis(5,[23 35]),'TerminationMethod','Truncated','Algorithm','True APP');    
y=step(H, Data1);    
x=step(h,zeros(300,1),y);    
b=double(x >0);    
v=Data1-b }
```

Comment: there is a complete example to do this in the [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.appdecoder-class.html) if you expand the Examples section. Also available directly in matlab with  `help comm.appdecoder` or `help comm.ConvolutionalEncoder`

Comment: if u look at the code, it has not any problem and no error face it , but its result is not logical, i mean v=Data1-b which should be zero but it is not.